# If the Khutbah is heard from far away place, not in the vicinity of the mosque, should the one who hears listen attentively?

Tags: salat, jumuah, khutbah

In many places, the Friday khutbah from the mosque is transmitted through loudspeakers which are otherwise used for Adhan and Iqamah only.

Sometimes one may hear the khutbah while in the bathroom or while he is getting ready and may not be able to completely pay attention. Does this regard him to have broken the etiquette of listening attentively to the khutbah?

Also the women who are working in household, are they supposed to listen too?

Comment: Should I ask the second question about women separately?

Comment: That depends on whether or not the first question is answered with a yes.